# Missing necessary OAuth permissions on GCP Pub/Sub

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-platform, google-forms, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to follow [this](https://developers.google.com/forms/api/guides/push-notifications) guide here to get push notifications whenever a response has been submitted on a Google Forms form. All prerequisites have been completed, and I can successfully publish a message to my Pub/Sub Topic, which then forwards the message to my webhook, running on NestJS with TypeScript (so Node.js as the environment).

However, I can't wrap my head around an issue I'm having when trying to create a watch, so to link my form to the corresponding topic. According to the guide, it is sufficient to grant the system service account (forms-notifications@system.gserviceaccount.com) permission to publish to the topic and then create the watch by using the `googleapis` SDK.

Following the code example they provide, I am getting this error message:

```json
{
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Project does not have necessary OAuth permissions from authorizing user.",
  "errors": [{
    "message": "Project does not have necessary OAuth permissions from authorizing user.",
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "failedPrecondition"
  }],
  "status": "FAILED_PRECONDITION"
}
```

I've tried with more scopes, more roles, but nothing seems to help so far.
Please advise, I don't know what to try anymore...

Comment: It's interesting (relevant?) that the error says "from authorizing user" (and not account). The doc includes "the application must retain an OAuth grant from the authorized user with the required scope" and, the Python sample for [Create a Watch](https://developers.google.com/forms/api/guides/push-notifications#create_a_watch) uses `flow_from_clientsecrets` which prompts a human (user) to enter their credentials and authenticates against scopes. It's unclear to me whether the NodeJS code does this too and it should. I think the user must authenticate the code that creates a watch.

Comment: @DazWilkin Hm, I think you're onto something. Following the exact code they provide in the docs, I get an error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'redirect_uris')`, which I just thought of being a bug, but now that you're bringing this up it might make sense that in order to create a watch, the user that created the form must authorize the app to create a watch manually. I'll test it  with the OAuth flow and get back to you.. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like @DazWilkin was right, creating a watch only works when authorizing the app using an OAuth2 flow. Following the docs I created a consent screen and a client ID and was able to create a watch successfully. Cheers for the hint!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).